# If our role model is Stackoverflow.com should we considire how was looks like SO when it was young and new comunity

Tags: discussion

Referring to comments on my question [about making a list](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/1936/can-we-make-a-list-of-analog-persons-in-between-christianity-judaism-and-islam) I wondering if our role model is SO then we should have behovar as it has SO in early time of creation.
Islam.SE is young and as I remember at SO there was questions such as , List of free DOT.NET Libraries or Programmers cartons and programmers yokes or What to write on programmer's birthday cake. 
Also there was similar questions at Serverfault.com as list of free software that helps administrators or List of commands in command prompt, even on Superuser.com there also was questions like Must have apps for pocket-pc and so on.
Most of these question today is declared as of-topics.
It is easy now for these sites to ban question like this when they have large popularity.
So I asking, Should we allow and support this kinds of question until we are still small,
For me question like this is something that make more interesting others to start actively participate.

Comment: I think the referenced question is fine. It can be a complete list and be with little or no subjectivity at all.

Comment: @Power-Inside Should we start build that list ?

Answer (score 3):

I disagree. One of the reasons I use this site, rather than tons of other forum sites and look-alike QA sites is that I trust SE network's expertise and experience in the area of QA format. If we were to disregard what SE learned along the way, up until this day, in this area, what different would we be from other new and inexperienced QA sites. We should stick to guidelines and framework SE provides us, until it is practically proven bad practice.

Answer (score 1):

Stack Overflow itself evolves and changes over time; this is why they even have a tag for "historical questions which were awesome, but are now not a good fit for the SO site."

It makes more sense to go with contemporary SO as our model; that's SO after years of finding and fixing problems with their site model.

Wallahu a'lam.

Comment: Actually, SO is a bad role-model, period (IMO). The site abounds in VLQ posts/etc, and community moderation doesn't really work. Besides that, there is the scale of the thing. I'd suggest you look at sites which have a medium level of activity (eg, English or something) as a role model. Even better, try not to imitate any site--mould your own! (Though try to stay within SE-wide policies) :D